# Unity: Type registered with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager is not being Singleton

Tags: wpf, singleton, unity-container, prism

I have an issue with a Unity Container in a WPF application. I am using Prism with UnityBootstrapper. I need to register a class as a singleton. This is the class:

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private string connectionString;

    public RepositoryBase(string conne)
    {
        connectionString = conne;
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> Get()
    {
        var db = GetDbConnection();
        var value = await db.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<T>(recursive: true);
        CloseDatabaseConnection(db);
        return value;
    }      
}
```

In the bootstrapper, I register the above type as follows:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    var assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
    path = Path.Combine(path, "Data.db3");
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Data.RepositoryBase<>), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(path));

    base.ConfigureContainer();
}
```

However, if I place a breakpoint in the constructor of the RepositoryBase class, I can see it breaks several times.
Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you injecting/resolving the type? Just through constructor injection? Which type are you using for `T`? When your code breaks, is T the same type more than once? Each generic instance of your type will be a separate class and will therefore cause there to be more than one instance of the generic interface. Are you expecting one single instance even for different generic types?

Comment: Yes.... I was expecting one single instance even for different generic types. Okey... so mystery solved. Thanks Charleh!

Comment: See here if you are interested in how generics work at run time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time